# Django Many-to-Many query all() returns empty set

Tags: python, django

As per the [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships) I created a relationship between people and dates for a museum application.

First the models (with unnecessary fields removed):

```
class Agent(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    dates = models.ManyToManyField(HistoricDate, 'date_for_agent', models.CASCADE, through='AgentDateType')
    . . . .

class HistoricDate(models.Model):
    display = models.CharField(max_length=255, help_text='Textual representation of date')
    earliest = models.CharField(max_length=15, blank=True)
    earliest_accuracy = models.BooleanField(default=False, verbose_name="circa")
    latest = models.CharField(max_length=15, blank=True)
    latest_accuracy = models.BooleanField(default=False, verbose_name="circa")

class AgentDateType(models.Model):
    datation = models.ForeignKey(HistoricDate, models.PROTECT)
    dated = models.ForeignKey(Agent, models.CASCADE)
    date_type = models.CharField(max_length=31, choices=date_types)
    . . . .
```

Then the test:

```
caesar = Agent.objects.create(name="Gaius Julius Caesar", name_type="personal", culture="Ancient Rome", display="Julius Caesar (Roman, 100–44 B.C.)")
c_life = HistoricDate.objects.create(display="13 July 100–15 March 44 B.C.", earliest="-100-07-13", earliest_accuracy=False, latest="-44-03-15", latest_accuracy=False)
c_act = HistoricDate.objects.create(display="60–44 B.C.", earliest="-60", earliest_accuracy=False, latest="-44-03-15", latest_accuracy=False)

caesar_lives = AgentDateType.objects.create(dated=caesar, datation=c_life, source="Suetonius, Lives of the Caesars", date_type="life")
caesar_acts = AgentDateType.objects.create(dated=caesar, datation=c_act, source="Livy", date_type="activity")
```

Now the following queries return the expected sets:

```
AgentDateType.objects.all()
c_life.date_for_agent.all()
c_act.date_for_agent.all()
```

However, `caesar.dates.all()`, which should be the most straightforward, returns an empty set. What gives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django's `ManyToManyField` takes positional arguments which are not in the order you've provided. See the [source for M2M](https://docs.djangoproject.com/fr/1.10/_modules/django/db/models/fields/related/#ManyToManyField). I suggest you use keyword arguments, as positional arguments can cause problem let alone even change between minor versions.

Comment: Thanks! I did not pay attention to the fact that ManyToManyField does not accept an `on_delete` argument. On second thought, it's sort of obvious from the concept...

Comment: If you really want to have a cascading effect (although I don't know which use case you could have for that), you can use your `through` table to enforce that.